# I am facing issue with npm install in Azure CICD pipeline

Tags: angular, azure, npm-install

node version = v16.20.1

npm version = 8.15.0

while doing npm install I am getting the following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHcli.png)

Here the pipeline was unable to install swiper module. which was working fine in local machine. Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

I tried by changing the node version from 14 to 16.x but no luck.

Comment: same pipe line working fine earlier but now I added one new library in package.json then I am facing this issue.

"@realpage/raul3": "^0.38.0",  I this package there is subpackage call swiper while installing this swiper I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the swiper package in my react app and added npm install task, The command ran successfully.

```js
npm install swiper
```

My package.json:-

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "swiper": "^10.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Push this changes to your Azure repository and then. If the npm module is giving an error locally. run the commands below to resolve it:-

```js
npm cache clean --force
```

```js
npm install -g npm@latest
```

```js
node -v
npm -v
```

I tried running npm install command in my pipeline build and deploy and it worked successfully, Refer below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

 
  azureSubscription: 'xxxx'


  webAppName: 'siliconwebapp128'

  
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapp128'

 
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: Npm@1
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: siliconwebapp128'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm cache clean --force
                npm install -g npm@latest
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

**My package.json in Azure repository:-**

[image]

An alternative code to run the npm commands:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '16.x'
      checkLatest: true

 
  - script: npm cache clean --force
    displayName: 'npm cache'
  - script: npm install
    displayName: 'npm install'
```

Comment: Here I found a very strange thing as in azure server while installing swiper module along with other packages nodemodules/swiper folder is getting deleted in middle of installation do you know what might be the reasons?